# maven-enunciate-plugin NullPointerException generating docs

Tags: maven, enunciate

I'm trying to run the maven-enunciate-plugin:1.26.2:docs and facing a NUllPointerException.

The only thing I want is its documentation generation as described here http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Documentation+Only, so my pom.xml is as:

```
...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.26.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <docsDir>${project.build.directory}/docs</docsDir>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>docs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>

...
```

But, it launches:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Problem assembling the enunciate app.
at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.execute(DocsMojo.java:100)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.java_client.JavaClientDeploymentModule.isGenerateJsonJar(JavaClientDeploymentModule.java:892)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.java_client.JavaClientDeploymentModule.doCompile(JavaClientDeploymentModule.java:501)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.BasicDeploymentModule.step(BasicDeploymentModule.java:113)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.doCompile(Enunciate.java:286)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.step(Enunciate.java:1738)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.stepTo(Enunciate.java:1766)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.execute(DocsMojo.java:96)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have the following suggestion: find source code of this particular version of the plugin and see what's happening on line 100 of `DocsMojo`. Most probably, you're missing some parameter in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try version 1.27. If it still happens, open up a bug.

Answer (score 0):

For the record. I was using v.1.27 and ran into this problem: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-771 then I bumped to v.1.28 and got the mentioned problem above.